# MYSQL Joined Tables with WHERE Criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

1. Component - Primary Key: Cid
2. Element - Primary Key: Eid, Foreign Key: Cid, Other fields: Companyid and Yearid

I need some advice on a JOIN query:

```
SELECT Cid, Eid 
FROM Component 
JOIN Element ON Cid=Eid 
WHERE (Cid = X and Companyid=Y and Yearid = Z)
```

I want return all the Component rows and only populate the Element fields where they exist and also if they exist for a specific company and year.

In the statement above, the criteria for the Companyid and Yearid return zero rows if there are no entries in the Element table.

Many thanks

Comment: Creating table with only 1 field? Are you kidding?

Comment: @edrich - There are several fields, I am trying to understand the query structure which I have been struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` to get rows in the first table that don't have matching rows in the second table. In addition, any filtering on the second table must be done in the `ON` clause. Otherwise, the `NULL` values from the nonexistent rows will fail the `WHERE` test, and remove those rows from the result. So it should be:

```
SELECT Cid, Eid 
FROM Component 
LEFT JOIN Element ON Cid = Eid AND Companyid=Y and Yearid = Z
WHERE Eid = X
```

Comment: It is returning all Component records and Nulls for Element records which is correct, the Component records need to be filtered by the Cid criteria, should I add these to a WHERE Criteria?

Comment: Since `Cid = Eid`, you should filter on `Eid`.

Comment: Maybe the join criteria should be `C.Cid = E.Cid`? That's what the foreign key is usually for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Cid, Eid 
FROM Component 
LEFT JOIN Element ON Cid = Eid 
WHERE (Cid = X and Companyid=Y and Yearid = Z)
```

Comment: Still returns no result, element is currently an empty table

Comment: Just send me the tables scripts. In the element table you should have ComponentId column If youtry to match the componentid with the elementid it doesn't work :)

Comment: you figured it out .. :)